# Still missing mscvpXXXd.dll after installed corresponding distribution package?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed on my PC, and I have also installed Miscrosoft Visual C++ 2012/2013 Redistributable packages, both x86/x64 version. Here is my problem that I have only got msvcp110.dll/msvcp120.dll in my System32/SysWOW64 but no msvcp120d.dll/msvcp110d.dll, like below picture.

[image]

This makes me can only build some project in release mode. Also, I don't know what's those msvcp110_clr0400.dll/msvcp110_win.dll for.

Anyone knows why those msvcpXXXd.dll are missing? Thank you!

Comment: Because they only are installed by the VS installer.  You have msvcp140d.dll, the version for VS2015.  But you do not have VS2012 and VS2013 installed.  So this is not a problem.

Comment: So if I need to debug some project using msvcp120d.dll in VS2015, I must copy it to the system folder manully?